# Hexadecimal to Base64 in python but I get the wrong result

Tags: python, base64, hex

```
hex_characters = {'0': '0000', '1': '0001', '2': '0010', '3': '0011', '4': '0100', '5': '0101', '6': '0110', '7': '0111', '8': '1000', '9': '1001',
    'a': '1010', 'b': '1011', 'c': '1100', 'd': '1101', 'e': '1110', 'f': '1111'}
    b64_characters = {
     '000000': 'A', '000001': 'B', '000010': 'C', '000011': 'D', '000100': 'E', '000101': 'F',
     '000110': 'G', '000111': 'H', '001000': 'I', '001001': 'J', '001010': 'K', '001011': 'L', '001100': 'M', '001101': 'N',
     '001110': 'O', '001111': 'P', '010000': 'Q', '010001': 'R', '010010': 'S', '010011': 'T', '010100': 'U', '010101': 'V',
     '010110': 'W', '010111': 'X', '011000': 'Y', '011001': 'Z', '011010': 'a', '011011': 'b', '011100': 'c', '011101': 'd',
     '011110': 'e', '011111': 'f', '100000': 'g', '100001': 'h', '100010': 'i', '100011': 'j', '100100': 'k', '100101': 'l',
     '100110': 'm', '100111': 'n', '101000': 'o', '101001': 'p', '101010': 'q', '101011': 'r', '101100': 's', '101101': 't',
     '101110': 'u', '101111': 'v', '110000': 'w', '110001': 'x', '110010': 'y', '110011': 'z', '110100': '0', '110101': '1',
     '110110': '2', '110111': '3', '111000': '4', '111001': '5', '111010': '6', '111011': '7', '111100': '8', '111101': '9',
     '111110': '+', '111111': '/'
     }
    
    def hex_to_b64(s):
        b16 = hex_characters    
        b64 = b64_characters    
        k = 0
        g = 0
        bin_list = list()      
        b64_list = list()      
        bin_string = ''         
        b64_string = ''      
        for i in s:
            b = s[k]
            bin_list.append(b16.get(b))   
            k += 1
        
        a = bin_string.join(bin_list)   
        a_split_in_six = [(a[i:i+6]) for i in range(0, len(a), 6)]  
        for i in a_split_in_six:
            m = a_split_in_six[g]
            b64_list.append(b64.get(m))
            g += 1
        b64_list_without_none = ['=' if x is None else x for x in b64_list]
        lex = b64_string.join(b64_list_without_none)
        return lex
    
    
    print(hex_to_b64('4a1b48d7322394a78326cd283f0834093e65421a7e98e90e5b452d160b5d07d8'))
```

I wrote this code to convert an hexa string to a base64 one but the result I get is "ShtI1zIjlKeDJs0oPwg0CT5lQhp+mOkOW0UtFgtdB9=" and the correct one is "ShtI1zIjlKeDJs0oPwg0CT5lQhp+mOkOW0UtFgtdB9g=" (notice the missing g at the end). Can someone explain me why I am wrong?

Comment: are you implementing this to understand how it works? otherwise: python has base64 built-in: https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#module-base64

Comment: Actually It's an assignment that I was given